# Proving or disproving a statement about continuity and limits

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-writing

[image]

So I've spent a few hours trying to find a counter example to this statement, and then gave up and spent additional few hours trying to prove it and Ive finally became frustrated with this problem. :)
I seem to get stuck in the scenario where $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ < 0, I'm just unable to find an epsilon that will satisfy all the conditions.. plus I'm not even sure if the statement is true or false anymore..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's attempt a formal approach:

Let $f(1) = a \gt 0$.

Then for $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0: |x-1| < \delta \implies |f(x) - a| < \epsilon$.

Taking $\epsilon = a/2; f(x) \in (a/2, a), \forall x \in (1-\delta,1+\delta) $.

But we can choose $\alpha: \alpha, 1/\alpha \in (1-\delta, 1+\delta)$. Thus $f(\alpha)f(1/\alpha)>0$.

This gives us a contradiction. And hence $ f(1)\ngtr 0$.

Similarly we can show $f(1) \nless 0$.

And hence $f(1)=0$.

---

Additionally, it can be shown that $1 \lt \alpha \lt \min(1+\delta, \frac 1 {1-\delta})$ suffices above. Here's how:

One way of choosing $\alpha: \alpha, 1/\alpha \in (1-\delta, 1+\delta)$ is,

$1< \alpha < 1+\delta; 1-\delta<1/\alpha<1$ (we take $\alpha>1; \implies 1/\alpha < 1$)

$\implies 1< \alpha < 1+\delta; 1<\alpha<\frac{1}{1-\delta} \implies 1<\alpha < \min(1+\delta, \frac 1 {1-\delta})$

(you can take $\alpha<1$ and find another possible choice for $\alpha$)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I tried to do it your way from first, I got that a/2<f(X)<2a, and second, how can I justify picking an a? also I didn't quiet get what you did in the 1<a<min(x,y) inequality

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean $a$ or $\alpha$ in your comments. We are not picking $f(1)=a$, we are simply assuming $f(1)>0$ and deriving contradiction. We are choosing $\alpha$ however to show that $f(x).f(1/x)<0$ does not hold $\forall x$. I am editing the post to show how we arrive at choice for $\alpha$. Does this make sense?

Comment: what's the proof that there exist such a, 1/a? Because I can't seem to prove their existance..

Comment: A little update, I've used your suggestion and proven the existence of such x, that 1/x is also in the neighbourhood. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MathCurious you're welcome

Answer (score 3):

Take the limit in your inequality as $x \to 1$, which gives
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) f(1/x) = f(1)^2 \leq 0,
$$
where the equality uses the continuity of $f$ at $1$. Since a square is nonnegative, the only possibility that remains is $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! :) But am I missing something? Because it says the expression is negative for all positive x such that x is not 1..

Comment: You do not need the value at the point to get limits: if $f(x) \leq a$ for all $x$ near $c$, $x \neq c$, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \leq a$. Here, you want to show that for $x = 1$, the strict inequality does not hold!

Comment: But if f(1)^2 = f(1)*f(1/1), how can i justify using the inequation? since it works only for positive none 1 x's

Comment: The inequality does not need to hold at the point, and the "strictly less" becomes "less than or equal". Note that I am not saying to take $x = 1$ (which would require, as you say, the inequality to be true at $x = 1$), but to take the limit as $x \to 1$ (which, as I mentioned above, only requires the inequality to be true near $x=1$, but not necessarily *at* $x=1$).

Comment: I still don't quiet understand it.. in our definition of continuity the neighbourhood is |x-a|<δ, which means x can equal a and therefore when x->1, and we replace f(x) with f(1), it is actualy f(1) and not approaching f(1) so I don't see how I can explain that "since f(1) is not really f(1) but approaches f(1)" the equation works..

Comment: It may depend on your definitions, but typically, the definition of **limit** does not include the point itself: if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-\ell| <\epsilon$. What I am saying here is the following fact: if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \ell$ and $f(x) \leq c$ for all $x$ near $a$ and $x \neq a$, then $\ell \leq c$. In my answer, I use this result and the fact that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) f(1/x) = f(1)^2$, which uses the **continuity** of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $ (x_n) \to 1 $. Can you find the limit of $ \left( \dfrac{1}{x_n} \right) $. Now assume $ f(1) \ne 0 $, so without loss of generality we can claim $ f(1) > 0 $.
Try reaching a contradiction using $ f(x_n) $ and $ f(\frac{1}{x_n}) $.

Comment: I've been sitting on this problem for a few days now with no luck.. can you elaborate what exactly is your way of prooving it because I don't quiet get it..