# Intermediate Value Theorem Prove\Disprove Question

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing

I would appreciate your help regarding this prove/disprove:

--

Let $f:(0, \infty) \to R$ be a continuous function at $x_{0}=1$ which $f(x)\cdot f(\frac{1}{x})<0$ for every $0 < x \neq 1$.

So $f(1)=0$.

--

I have tried to prove it with no luck, than tried to find a counter-example with no luck...

Any help will be amazing!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Consider the cases $f(1-\frac 1 n) \leq 0$ for infinitely many $n$ and $f(1-\frac 1 n) \geq 0$ for infinitely many $n$. In both case continuity gives $(f(1))^{2} \leq 0$.

Comment: Do you mean to look at a function $f(x)=1- \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: There is no counter-example. Prove that $f(1)$ must be $0$ using my hint.

Comment: Alright, will try, thanks a lot!

Comment: Take any open interval containing $1$. Show there are two points in that interval, one less than $1$ and one greater than $1$, where $f$ takes different signs. Since $f$ is continuous at $1$ ...

Comment: By the way, IVT is not applicable here.

Comment: So taking $(0,a)$ while $a>1$ or (0,2) will be enough for that?

Comment: No. Take *any* (fixed) interval, $(1-\delta, 1+\delta)$. Take any two points in this interval, $a<1$ and $1/a>1$ (take $a$ close enough to $1$ to insure $1/a$ is in the interval). You then have $f(a)f(1/a)<0$. This can not be if $f$ is continuous at $1$ with $f(1)\ne0$.

Comment: I would take $a= \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{a}=2$ will that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving or disproving a statement about continuity and limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964730/proving-or-disproving-a-statement-about-continuity-and-limits)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x_n = 1+\frac 1n$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x=1$ you have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac 1{x_n}\right)= f(1)$$

So, it follows

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(f(x_n)\cdot f\left(\frac 1{x_n}\right)\right)=\left(f(1)\right)^2 \leq 0$$

Hence, $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't understand what you did here unfortunately..

Comment: @Math4me : So, maybe you ask some questions about what you don't understand? But you may first look up the limit definition of continuity of a function and some standard results wrt. limit operations.

Comment: I know the limit definition, I agree with what you did, I just do not understand how you got there. And, why is $(f(1))^2 \leq 0$?

Comment: @Math4me
Maybe it helps to set $u_n = f(x_n)$ and $v_n=f\left(\frac 1{x_n}\right)$. Because of $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 1$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{x_n} = 1$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x=1$, you get $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n = f(1)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n = f(1)$.

Standard limit rules tell you $\lim_{n\to\infty}(u_nv_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}u_n\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}v_n = f(1)\cdot f(1) $.

It is given that $u_n\cdot v_n = f(x_n)\cdot f\left(\frac 1{x_n}\right)<0$ for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$. From this follows by a standard limit property that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(u_nv_n) \leq 0$.

Comment: I will try to think about that a little more. Thank you! :)