# Continuity and Intermediate Value Theorem.

Tags: continuity, proof-writing, proof-explanation, limits-without-lhopital

$$Duplicate$$
Please disregard this post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving or disproving a statement about continuity and limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964730/proving-or-disproving-a-statement-about-continuity-and-limits)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again?

Comment: Thanks for the notice! I wasn't sure how this site works regarding posting a new post if I failed to understand the help I was given in the old one. Will take it under consideration from now on!

Comment: Yes! Asking for clarifications through comments is much better then asking again the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $ f(1) \neq 0$ and $f$ is supposed to be continuous at $1$ then

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x) f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \left(\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x)\right)\left(\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) =f^2(1) \gt 0.$$

In contradiction with the given hypothesis $f(x) f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \lt 0$ which implies $ \lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x) f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le 0$. **Therefore $f(1) =0$.**

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping why we can use the given inequality is it's stated at it doesn't work for x=1.. I get that we don't "care" what happens at 1 itself, but when it comes to continuous functions shouldn't we?

Comment: Because if you look at the definition of $f(x)$ at $a$, you use $x$ values that are not equal to $a$. Always go back to the definitions!

Comment: But in the case of continuity, we say |x-a| < δ instead of 0<|x-a| < δ exactly for the reason that x can equal a, or am I missing something?

Comment: For continuity, you just add the property that the value of the map at the given point is equal to the limit of the map at that point. You don't need to change the definition of the limit.

Comment: That's what I don't get.. our definition states that it is continuous on the neighbourhood of "a", including in the point "a" itself.. the exact quote from the course book is ".. for every ϵ > 0 there exists a δ > 0 such that for every |x − a| < δ, we have | f(x) − f(a)| < ϵ."